# 127.0.0.1 didn't send any data error while click on go live

Tags: visual-studio, runtime-error

Microsoft Visual Studio Code:
When I click on go live, I am having this error 127.0.0.1 didn't send any data ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

I am new to VS so couldn't do much. I reinstalled Visual studio and deleted all the data related to it. But didn't resolve the issue. I am a student and recently started using VS. seeking guidance from the community.